# Overloading operator>>: cannot bind ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&’

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the operator in my header as such:

```
friend std::istream& operator>> ( std::istream& is, StudentRecord& sr );
```

and in my class:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is ,  StudentRecord& sr){
    is >> sr.name >>std::ws>> sr.surname>>std::ws>>sr.studentNumber>>std::ws;
    getline(is, sr.classRecord);
    return is;
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
std::basic_istream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&
```

in a database class:

```
void Database::read(string f)
{

    studRcrds.clear();
    std::ifstream in(f.c_str());
    string studLine;
    while (!(in.eof()))
    {

        getline(in,studLine);
        std::istringstream sin(studLine);
        StudentRecord newStudent();
        sin >> newStudent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how you call this operator.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Done, anymore addtions?

Comment: In function read StudentRecord newStudent(); means a function declaration. Change it to StudentRecord newStudent;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is a bit confusing, but it means there is no `operator>>` that can be used for `sin >> newStudent;`

That is because you have declared `newStudent` as a function (see [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)). The wording of the error is because there is an overload for rvalue streams that accepts anything on the right-hand side:

```
template<typename CharT, typename TraitsT, typename T>
basic_istream<CharT, TraitsT>&
operator>>(basic_istream<CharT, TraitsT>&& istr, T&&);
```

and because there is no matching operator for the function type of `newStudent` it tries to call that overload, which can't bind an rvalue-reference to `sin`.

The fix is to avoid the most vexing parse:

```
StudentRecord newStudent;
```

or:

```
StudentRecord newStudent{};
```

or:

```
StudentRecord newStudent = newStudent();
```

or similar. With that change `newStudent` has the right type and so can use your `operator>>` overload.

Answer (score -2):

You may also change your getline function:

**istream& getline(std::istream& is, StudentRecord& sr)**

without using a newStudent object.